# Find a cell of a row in a gridview and do something on OnRowDataBound

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I want to only set a single cell in a GridView row to Grey if the reader HasRows, on the OnRowDataBound event.
The code snippet changes the entire column color rather than a single cell.
For example: In the image I want only the cell next to "Jan" to be grey.

```
protected void setcolor(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e )
            {
                if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                {               
                    if (txtShopBranch.Text == "Area1")
                        {
                            int index = e.Row.RowIndex;
                            string checkdayone = "SELECT one FROM tblregulardays WHERE  months = 'Jan'  AND shopbranch = 'Area1' AND one = '1'";
                            NpgsqlCommand findDayOne = new NpgsqlCommand (checkdayone, con);
                            con.Open();
                            NpgsqlDataReader reader = findDayOne.ExecuteReader();
                            if(reader.HasRows)
                                {
                                    e.Row.Cells[32].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray;
                                }
                            else
                                {   
                                    e.Row.Cells[32].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
                                }
                            con.Close();
                    }

                }
            }
```

[image]

Comment: Your code should work. So i assume that your query doesn't work and always returns a reow. Have you used the debugger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the same static sql query for every row:

```
string checkdayone = @"SELECT one FROM tblregulardays 
                       WHERE  months = 'Jan'  
                          AND shopbranch = 'Area1' 
                          AND one = '1'";
```

so of course will always yield the same result. You have to use a parameterized query. Maybe:

```
string month = e.Row.Cells[31].Text.Trim();

string checkdayone = @"SELECT one FROM tblregulardays 
                       WHERE  months = @Month  
                          AND shopbranch = 'Area1' 
                          AND one = '1'";

NpgsqlCommand findDayOne = new NpgsqlCommand (checkdayone, con);
findDayOne.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Month", month);
```

Comment: I would not use the `Text` value from the cell, but rather cast the row DataItem back to a DataRowView and use that: `DataRowView row = e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView` and then `string month = row["column"].ToString();`. If the cell value is a formatted date or number you could get wrong values.